# Display the name on incoming phone calls

Tags: java, sip, telephony

I have a Java application (using Swing) that must display the details of the customer when a call is received.

1. Is it possible to pass the phone number from a softphone (SIP) to my Java Swing application so that it can display the details?
2. IS there any other way or program to do this?

Comment: Which softphone you are using?

Comment: Well, that depends on the SIP application you use. If it provides some kind of api - you should use it. If not - the only way to find the number is through memory-hacking or network-hacking.

Comment: Not nearly enough information. There are many ways to do this (I'm assuming you are working on some form of contact-center solution). Connecting the physical phone to the PC and integrating with (J)TAPI or some proprietary API is one way. Integrating over some form of CT link directly with the PBX or call-center appliance is another. It all depends what systems you are running and what capabilities they have.

Comment: softphone is Linphone. this is actually restuarant reservation application which needs to disply the customer details based on the incoming phone number. i really dont know where to start with.thanks for your help

Comment: Linphone is opensource, well-documented project that even comes with an SDK. That's why -1 from me.

Comment: is it possible to program so that irrespective of the ip phones i can get the phone number.

Comment: thank you Max, i understood your point only after Rahuls answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use Linphone SDK with your java application. You probably need to show the softphone from your java application or receive call in your application using SDK of linphone.

Comment: Thank you Mr Rahul, i dint  really know where to start with. Can you adivce me any other voip sdk in java

Comment: How can i show the linphone from my applciation, atleast steps would highly helpful

Comment: you can have a look at http://peers.sourceforge.net/, it is good and have good documentation. Also have a look at http://java.net/projects/jsip

Comment: thats great, i came across this many times, but i dint think tat it should be called from my application. Thanks a lot. i will start working on it. may need you help in future

Comment: You can ask anytime or drop me a line on rahulrborkar@gmail.com

Comment: as per the instructions on peers--                                   svn co https://peers.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/peers/trunk peers when i enter this line i get error as cannot connect to server any idea

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

Use Tropo.com to send a callback http request during incoming calls.
Use a PBX such as FusionPBX that can lookup names from numbers on-the-fly and insert it into the SIP message before it's sent to your phone.
If your phone supports syslog, you could tap into the information that way, too.