# TAPI in oracle 10g form

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I m new here, I had a question that how to get caller id in oracle 10g forms as we get in C# through TAPI. Please anyone can help me i have to create form which show the telephone number of the caller.

Comment: Why do you think this is an Oracle question and not a c# question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128204/how-detect-caller-id-from-phone-line

Comment: I don't know. kindly if you have any kind of information please help me.

Comment: There are APIs available see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13395/T267990T267993.htm or https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e13402/T278837T278840.htm) but they seem built more for Java.  Why the desire to move from a C# solution to an older (basically) obsolete technology?

Comment: No actually i need in oracle 10g not in C#.

Comment: And i also need API for Oracle 10 G with their complete Steps of installation to running form.

Comment: @khurramkhan One approach is to build the GUI using Java Swing, use API to achieve your expected output and then integrate Swing to Oracle Forms.

Comment: @user75ponic plz tell me name of any api that i will use for that purpose and kindly any link about java Swing how to design it and how to integrate it with oracle...

Comment: @khurramkhan There will be many articles to display caller information using Java, to be honest I have never used TAPI. I would suggest doing a Google search.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699400/display-the-name-on-incoming-phone-calls) Regarding your second question [see](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-14848846.html) this as an example.

Comment: ok i got the point from quetion that first i have to create an java application that will receive telephone calls then that application will be integrated in oracle m i right @user75ponic

Comment: @khurramkhan Yes, absolutely. First, create a Java Swing application with  API to detect incoming telephone call details which should be followed by integration with Oracle Forms.

Comment: any source code of java swing application or any api plzzzz @user75ponic

Comment: and also need steps to configure telephone set with my system

Comment: @khurramkhan I do not have source code for Java Swing. Internet would be a good resource to get going with Java Swing.